# value of variable not change in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to assign value of variable in id of different element in dynamically generated row but it is not changed .code is as given below.row is generated on click of Add button i.e insRow() function.' Please guide.

```
var i=0;
 function insRow() {
 i++;
 let newRowContent = "<tr>"
 +"<td> <select class='form-control' id='upcList'+i><option selected='selected'>Select</option></select></td>"
                                      
 + "<td><input id='tdesc+i' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
 + "<td><input id='tamnt+i' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
 +"<td><input id='trem+i' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
 +"<td><input type='button' style='margin-left:2%;' value='Add' id='abc' class='btnrowvalue3' onclick='insRow()' /></td>"
 + "</tr>";
 $("#ipcelltbll tbody").append(newRowContent);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate it into the string

```
let newRowContent = "<tr>"
     +"<td> <select class='form-control' id='upcList" + i + "'><option selected='selected'>Select</option></select></td>"
     ....
```

You have the same mistake in a few other places too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coding it like the others answer suggest (concat multiple strings), I'd personally use template literals. They look a lot cleaner and I think its a lot more readable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
let i = 0;

function insRow() {
  i++;
  let newRowContent = `<tr>
    <td> <select class='form-control' id='upcList${i}'><option selected='selected'>Select</option></select></td>
    <td><input id='tdesc${i}' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>
    <td><input id='tamnt${i}' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>
    <td><input id='trem${i}' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>
    <td><input type='button' style='margin-left:2%;' value='Add' id='abc' class='btnrowvalue3' onclick='insRow()' /></td>
    </tr>`;
  $("#ipcelltbll tbody").append(newRowContent);
}

insRow();
insRow();
insRow();
insRow();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ipcelltbll">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have hardcoded "i" into the text

```
var i=0;
 function insRow() {
 i++;
 let newRowContent = "<tr>"
 +"<td> <select class='form-control' id='upcList" + i +"'><option selected='selected'>Select</option></select></td>"
                                      
 + "<td><input id='tdesc" + i + "' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
 + "<td><input id='tamnt" + i + "' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
 +"<td><input id='trem" + i + "' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
 +"<td><input type='button' style='margin-left:2%;' value='Add' id='abc' class='btnrowvalue3' onclick='insRow()' /></td>"
 + "</tr>";
 $("#ipcelltbll tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't shown how you are binding your `insRow` function to the click event of the button - that may be the issue, but it's hard to know without looking.

The `i` variable is defined outside the scope of `insRow` - it's not good to have global variables like this. Why do you need `i` at all? I don't see it used here.